# Vuejs. I can't transfer data to an Object

Tags: vue.js

I would like to catch uploaded file in FilePond. but the base64 of the file isn't transfered to my object. Any solutions?

**In template**

```
    <FilePond
   v-on:addfile="catch"
    />
```

**In Data**

```
  data:function() {
        return {
    image:'',
   }}
```

**in Method**

```
catch: function(fieldName, file) {
    console.log('#', file.file) // The Blop format file appears in console

    const reader = new FileReader(); //convert to base64
    reader.readAsDataURL(file.file); 
    reader.onloadend = function() {

   console.log('yy',reader.result); // Base64 image appears in console 
   (600000 carac)
    this.image= reader.result ; // HERE, the object still blank

    } },
```

Error in console :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'image' of undefined
at FileReader.reader.onloadend
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` keyword is shadowed by the `onloadend` function, save `this` before defining the function and then reference it inside:

```js
methods: {
  catch: function(fieldName, file) {
    // ...
    var ref = this
    reader.onloadend = function() {
      ref.image= reader.result   // use ref here
    }
    // ...
  }
}
```